# In Scala, how do I translate from hard coded files to using resources?

Tags: scala

At the moment I have something similar to the following

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(new File(myFile)).getLines) {}
```

Suppose instead of myFile I want to use

```
getClass.getResource("/filename")
```

What is the syntax for doing this whilst retaining the ability to still read line by line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/filename"))`